# Typescript File 404 Not Found With Karma and Angular2 Test - Chrome Debugging

Tags: angular, karma-runner, systemjs

I have angular2 unit tests working with Karma and Jasmine.

The tests are running off the javascript file with the js.map(source map) pointing to a TS (typescript) file in the same directory.

When I click on the typescript file in the browser, I get a 404 error.

What do I need todo to get karma to map correctly to my typescript file?

How can I debug chrome to find out what URL(Path) it is using when I try to get the Typescript file?